# Scoping require class loading, etc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a file booking.rb in my model directory. It contains the class definition

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.setup_connection  
    wsdlurl = 'http://10.14.47.201:7001xxx/webservice/RetrieveBookingsByCCLV1_01.wsdl'  
    factory = SOAP::WSDLDriverFactory.new(wsdlurl)  
    @@driver = factory.create_rpc_driver  
    @@driver.return_response_as_xml = true  
  end
end
```

I attempt to invoke this method from my application.rb see code below.

```
module PNR2
  class Application < Rails::Application  
    ...  
    ...  
    Booking.setup_connection  
  end  
end
```

This fails with the following when I run the app...

```
  C:/Users/sg0209028/RubymineProjects/PNR2/config/application.rb:49:in   `<class:Application>': uninitialized constant PNR2::Application::Booking (NameError)  
 from C:/Users/sg0209028/RubymineProjects/PNR2/config/application.rb:18:in `<module:PNR2>'  
 from C:/Users/sg0209028/RubymineProjects/PNR2/config/application.rb:17:in `<top (required)>
```

The reason for the reference to line 49 is that I removed all the comments in this application.rb file to avoid taking space in this note. Line 49 in the original was the Booking.setup_connection line.

I am clearly not understanding how name scoping is working in Rails 3. Maybe I also don't understand when I should be invoking a class method to set up a constant in a Model object. It feels like that should be an application initialization task, but maybe that request should be somewhere else.

Ib case anyone is wondering, I have had this code and invocation of the appropriate web services working in a straingth Ruby (non rails) environment.

Below is the code for that

```
require 'soap/wsdlDriver'
require 'rexml/document'
require 'soap/rpc/driver'
WSDL_URL = "http://10.14.47.202:7001/xxx/webservice/RetrieveBookingsByCCLV1_01.wsdl"
factory = SOAP::WSDLDriverFactory.new(WSDL_URL)
driver = factory.create_rpc_driver
driver.return_response_as_xml = true
params = {"ccl" => "Booking[BookingName[BookingNameItem[TicketNumber > \"123456789\"]]]", "xmlFormat" => "DefaultBooking"}
response = driver.RetrieveBookingsByCCL(params)
doc = REXML::Document.new response
puts "Number of PNRs = " + REXML::XPath.first(doc, "//count").text
doc.elements.each ("//originCity") {|element| puts "Element = " + element.text}
```

Can anyone please give this newbie some pointers? Oh and yes I do realize that invoking some SOAP based services instead of back ending with a database is going to have some issues. That I am prepared for once I get the connection to work!

Thanks in advance

Chris

Answer (score 0):

I just realized you were trying to use the Booking class in your application.rb file. I think you are going to have issues because at this point your application is not fully configured, but if you can get around those, to actually use the model, you'll have to require the file at the top of your application.rb file:

```
require 'rails/all'
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '../app/models/booking')
```

Comment: Pan, again, thanks for that. It is now working but with a slight mod - needed to m ake sure app was included properly in the path - '../app/models/booking'. Much appreciated

Comment: Glad it worked out. Updated my answer to add the /app part of the path as well.

Answer (score 0):

`Booking` is in the root-namespace, and you're calling the function (on your line 49) within the `PNR2::Application` namespace. You should change it to:

```
module PNR2
  class Application < Rails::Application  
    ...  
    ...  
    ::Booking.setup_connection  
  end  
end
```